# Condición consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Buen día,

Tengo un sistema en C#, en el cual los usuarios realizan tareas en base a un cliente, estas tareas pueden ser confidenciales entre dos personas o abiertas, es decir, que todos pueden verlas al consultar el cliente. Mi problema viene ahora: cuando un usuario del sistema consulta el cliente y este usuario no tiene relación con la tarea confidencial, no se le debe mostrar, por lo tanto, debe ver todo el listado de tareas de ese cliente, excluyendo las tareas confidenciales donde el no participe, pero sí debe ver las que el tiene con otra persona o le han asignado. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esa lógica en el `WHERE` de mi consulta?

```
    SELECT t.IdTareas
    ,t.Asunto
    ,t.IdContacto
    ,cont.fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social AS Contacto
    ,t.AsignadoPor
    ,UserProfileAsignador.UserName AS Asignador
    ,UserProfileAsignador.Puesto AS [Puesto Asignador]
    ,t.ControladaPor
    ,UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserName AS Controlador
    ,UserProfileAsignadoPor.Puesto AS [Puesto Controlador]
    ,t.AsignadaA
    ,UserProfileAsignadaA.userName AS Realizador
    ,UserProfileAsignadaA.Puesto AS [Puesto Realizador]
    ,t.FechaAsignacion
    ,t.FechaDeVencimiento
    ,t.FechaCambioDeEstado
    ,t.Observaciones
    ,t.Estado AS IdEstado
    ,et.Estado AS Estado
    ,Confidencial
FROM SEF.dbo.Tareas AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.TareasEstados AS et ON t.Estado = et.IdEstadosDeTareas
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF_CONFIG.dbo.vi_list_contactos AS cont ON t.IdContacto = cont.IdContacto
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignador ON t.AsignadoPor = UserProfileAsignador.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadoPor ON t.ControladaPor = UserProfileAsignadoPor.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.UserProfile AS UserProfileAsignadaA ON t.AsignadaA = UserProfileAsignadaA.UserId
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.Puestos AS PuestoAsignador ON UserProfileAsignador.Puesto = PuestoAsignador.IdPuesto
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.Puestos AS PuestosControlador ON UserProfileAsignadoPor.Puesto = PuestosControlador.IdPuesto
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEF.dbo.Puestos AS PuestosRealizador ON UserProfileAsignadaA.Puesto = PuestosRealizador.IdPuesto
WHERE t.IdContacto = @cod_contacto
    AND (
        t.AsignadaA = @cod_usuario
        OR t.ControladaPor = @cod_usuario
        OR t.AsignadoPor = @cod_usuario
        OR t.Confidencial = 0
        OR EXISTS (
            SELECT Sector
            FROM SEF_CONFIG.dbo.PermisoTareasConfidencial
            WHERE Sector = @cod_sector
            )
        )
ORDER BY IdTareas ASC;
```

Comment: Sería gentil indicar cómo es la estructura de datos para no tener que generarla mentalmente a partir de la consulta. Así que te respondo como creo que sería conceptualmente: `WHERE t.IdCliente = @id_cliente AND (t.AsignadaA = @cod_contacto OR t.ControladaPor = @cod_contacto OR t.Confidencial = 0)`. No me queda en claro si el `@cod_contacto` que recibes tiene relación con lo que hay en `AsignadoPor`, `AsignadaA`, etc., o bien si hay que hacer un join adicional con alguna otra tabla por cada uno de ellos. ¿Influye en algo a esta pregunta que sea en C#?

Comment: No influye que esté hecho en C#. Te explico un poco más, una tarea la crea un asignador, que a su vez en el 99% de los casos es el mismo controlador, muy rara vez se cambia el controlador, pero puede pasar que la tarea pase a controlarse por alguien más, en fin, esto es asignado a una persona. La idea de mi consulta es excluir todas las tareas confidenciales (confidencial=1) donde el asignador, controlador o realizador NO es el usuario actual del sistema. No se si me doy a entender bien o te puedo facilitar otro dato para que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: El cod_contacto, no es más que el ID del cliente que quiero consultar la tarea, solo que asi le llamo a mi parametro en DevExpress de C#

Comment: Otro punto que te agrego para poder guiarte correctamente es el siguiente. El usuario debe ser capaz de ver todas las tareas, de todos los usuarios que no sean confidenciales, en base a ese cliente o contacto, pero solo y unicamente se deben excluir aquellas tareas de ese contacto o cliente que sean confidenciales y no correspondan con el usuario que inició sesión. Es decir, ese usuario no es asignador, controlador ni realizador de esa tarea confidencial.

Comment: Lo que tengo en mente, pero no se como ejecutarlo es una condición WHERE tipo... WHERE t.IdContacto = cod_contacto AND t.IdTareas <> (excluya todas las tareas donde confidencial = 1 y el usuario es distinto al actual del sistema tipo t.AsignadoPor <> cod_usuario_actual)

Comment: Bueno, entonces el código que te puse debería funcionar, sólo cambiando la variable `@cod_contacto` por `@cod_usuario_actual` y agregando la condición para `AsignadoPor` (y corregir lo de `IdContacto`, porque no era claro). ¿O tiene algo equivocado esa condición?

Comment: Tu condición busca las tareas de ese usuario especifico, no es lo que necesito, es al contrario. Necesito poder ver la tarea de TODOS los usuarios y EXCLUIR las tareas confidenciales donde yo no tengo participacion siendo asignador, controlador o realizador.

Comment: No, busca de ese cliente específico, y tareas en las que el usuario esté involucrado o esa tarea no sea confidencial.

Comment: Si, tal cual, pero lo que necesito es que busque de ese cliente en especifico (ya lo hace), pero que me muestre todas las tareas como lo hace, pero excluyendo las tareas confidenciales donde yo no participo como asignador, controlador o realizador.

Comment: La idea es ver todas las tareas, de todos los usuarios. Eso es lo primordial, pero excluyendo como te digo, aquellas tareas confidenciales donde el usuario actual del sistema no participa en ninguno de los 03 pasos (asignador, controlador, realizador)

Comment: Sí, e insisto en que mi condición debería hacer eso. Creo que estás repitiendo la misma explicación sólo que con otras palabras. Ahí la agregué como respuesta, creo que utilizando los nombres que corresponden.

Comment: No pasa eso, te puedo subir una imagen del SQL para que veas, en verdad gracias por responderme tan seguido, eres de gran ayuda. Por eso quiero resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Trae de más o de menos? ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo de registros que falten o que sobren? Recomiendo editar la pregunta y copiar los resultados ahí como texto. Pero si se te complica mucho, se puede como imagen también. ¿Puede alguno de los 3 campos (`AsignadoPor`, etc.) ser `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a los comentarios, entiendo que la condición debería ser:

```
WHERE t.IdContacto = @cod_contacto
AND (t.AsignadaA = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.ControladaPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.AsignadoPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.Confidencial = 0)
```

Como verás, en primer lugar sólo trae tareas del cliente `@cod_contacto`, y además, se tiene que dar una de las otras cuatro condiciones: que el usuario actual esté en alguno de esos campos, o que la tarea no sea confidencial.

## Actualización

Para usuarios administrador (o gerentes) que pueden ver todo, puedes hacer así:

```
WHERE t.IdContacto = @cod_contacto
AND (t.AsignadaA = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.ControladaPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.AsignadoPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.Confidencial = 0
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SEF.dbo.UserProfile WHERE UserId = @cod_usuario_actual AND EsGerente = 1)
    )
```

O bien:

```
DECLARE @esAdmin AS BIT = 0;
SELECT TOP 1 @esAdmin = 1 FROM SEF.dbo.UserProfile WHERE UserId = @cod_usuario_actual AND EsGerente = 1;

SELECT t.IdTareas
...
WHERE t.IdContacto = @cod_contacto
AND (t.AsignadaA = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.ControladaPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.AsignadoPor = @cod_usuario_actual
    OR t.Confidencial = 0
    OR @esAdmin = 1)
```

*Nota: son queries escritos mentalmente, puede que necesiten alguna corrección de sintaxis.*

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias, con esto pude resolver esa primera duda, era yo quien estaba colocando mal los parámetros al buscar. ¡Esto funciona correctamente! Te hago una ultima consulta, como podría hacer para ver todas las tareas, de todos los usuarios (sin importar si es confidencial o no) en base a que un sector o usuario este habilitado con este permiso de visualización. Es decir, que por ejemplo mi usuario si sea capaz de ver todo o que mi sector o puesto de trabajo (ej. gerencia) pueda ver todo.

Comment: Listo, creo que no te fastidio más, acabo de pensarlo. En el C#, ejecuto un IF con dos consultas SQL, si el sector es autorizado, muestro una consulta, si no, muestro la consulta que resolvimos acá.

Comment: Depende de dónde esté esa información. Una opción sería agregar otro `OR` a la condición que sea algo así: `OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SEF.dbo.UserProfile WHERE UserId = @cod_usuario_actual AND EsGerente = 1)`. También podrías, en el mismo string de la consulta, hacer esta query al principio, guardar el resultado en una variable bit, y usarla luego en la condición. En cuanto menos dupliques código, mejor, porque si luego tienes que modificar algo, deberás hacerlo en dos lados. Si te funcionó, agradecería que marques la respuesta como aceptada, para que tu consulta no quede sin resolución.

Comment: Ahí actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta con la consulta ya funcional, en verdad gracias por la ayuda, es excelente conseguir gente desinteresada en ayudar. Gracias por todo amigo!

Comment: Muy bien, no hay por qué. El estándar de nombres no es muy bueno, es confuso y sería bueno mejorarlo, aunque eso suele ser complicado.

Comment: Si, es una tabla que tomé de otro programador y poco a poco la estoy adaptando a los estándares, en el día a día ya se me hizo fácil de leer, pero es complejo como dices, no está bien estandarizado y se presta a confundir. De nuevo, muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: No hay por qué. Sólo restaría aceptar mi respuesta para que tu consulta no quede como no resuelta. ;)